# Quartz job in Spring isn't started

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Spring's SchedulerFactoryBean to schedule a job dynamically.
Here is my Spring configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfigBean {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException{
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource source = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(dataSourceName);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() throws NamingException {
        SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean = null;
        try {
            schedulerFactoryBean = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
            schedulerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
            schedulerFactoryBean.setQuartzProperties(com.orca.integration.plugins.vs.broadpeak.admin.utils.Configuration.getQuartzProperties());
            schedulerFactoryBean.setAutoStartup(false);
        } catch (SchedulingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return schedulerFactoryBean;
    }
```

}

Here is my job:

```
@Component
public class MyJob extends QuartzJobBean {

    @Override
    public void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("Start job...");
}
}
```

This is where I'm dynamically scheduling the task:

```
@Component
public class MyManager {
    @Autowired
    private SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean;

    public void myMethod(String text, Calendar startDate) {
        logger.debug("BroadpeakDistributionManager.startRecordingChannel(); Parameters: recording channel ID=" + recordingChannel.getExternalId());

//      StartRecordJob.scheduleMe(text, startDate, "Start");

        JobDetailBean jobDetailBean = new JobDetailBean();
        jobDetailBean.setJobClass(MyJob.class);
        jobDetailBean.setName("name");
        jobDetailBean.afterPropertiesSet();

        SimpleTriggerBean simpleTriggerBean = new SimpleTriggerBean();
        simpleTriggerBean.setJobDetail(jobDetailBean);
        simpleTriggerBean.setName("Name");
        simpleTriggerBean.setStartTime(startDate.getTime());
        try {
            simpleTriggerBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        schedulerFactoryBean.setTriggers(new Trigger[] {simpleTriggerBean});
        schedulerFactoryBean.start();
    }
}
```

The job isn't started.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with programatically configuration with Spring. So I wrote this XML Spring application context configuration integrating it with Quartz.

Take a look:

```
<!-- You can inject other sping beans here -->
<bean id="myJob" class="your.package.here.MyJob "/>

<!-- Define your target method -->
<bean id="jobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
  <property name="targetObject" ref="myJob" />
  <property name="targetMethod" value="executeInternal" />
</bean>

<!-- trigger using unix expression -->
<bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="jobDetail" />
    <!-- run every morning at 6 AM -->
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 6 * * ?" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing the @EnableScheduling annotation?

Something like this :

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringConfigBean {
...
}
```

Comment: The @EnableScheduling annotation isn't necessary when using SchedulerFactoryBean directly.